# ActiveRecords display ISO8601 timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I do have a postgres DB which contains a timestamp. This timestamp follow the ISO standard and looks like:

```
2017-08-28 20:14:45.684926+00
```

I have used ActiveRecord to access the DB from Ruby/Sinatra environment but the ts returned is ISO8601.

Is there a way to force the formatting to ISO and not ISO8601 ?

I would like to avoid parsing the data once received.

Right now, I am using the command:

```
class ApiResponse < ActiveRecord::Base

  class << self

    def send_query(user, params)

      limit = params.include?('limit') ? params['limit'] : 50

      where_params = {
          userid: user,
          allowed_intent: true
      }

      ApiResponse.select([:id, :ts, :userid, :intent, :response])
          .where(where_params)
          .order(ts: :desc)
          .limit(limit).to_a

    end
end
```

The ApiResponse class is used to access the DB through ActiveRecord and it works fine. but the format is not correct. it shows :

```
2017-08-29T05:58:44.488Z
```

instead of something like

```
2017-08-28 20:14:45.684926+00
```

This format ISO is the one in the db

Any idea how to get the timestamp ts correctly formated as I expect inside the ActiveRecord call?

Comment: What is timestame? What is the difference between ISO and iso? What is ts? What is the difference between iso8601 and ISO8601?

Comment: What is the iso format that is not ISO8601, which you want the formatting to be?

Comment: @sawa ISO8601 look like : "2017-08-29T05:58:44.488Z" and ISO used by Postgres Db looks like : "2017-08-28 20:14:45.684926+00"

Comment: @sawa in postgres, timestamp is used to define the date/time at which you have created an element

Comment: “Any idea?” is not a valid question here on SO.

Comment: @Sep I didn't ask what timestamp is, I asked what timestame is.

Comment: @sawa it's a typo issue in the title

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some misunderstandings here:

1. Postgres uses ISO 8601 for output (the so called ISO, they are not different standards) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-datetime.html
2. ActiveRecord, I assume, returns an instance of `DateTime` class or something similar, and not a string in that format.
3. What you see is only a format used for displaying; you can use `strftime` to display the data in another format.

Comment: PG class is returning the formatting as PostGres standard which is "2017-08-28 20:14:45.684926+00". ActiveRecords follow the formatting ISO8601. using the strftime means I will have to parse each item of the array to change the format and it's time consuming JSON parsing is not a fast process. Or in that case, is there a way to directly format the result ActiveRecords called such as ts.format or strftime(ts)...

Comment: your ts is not string it is an instance of datetime or something  equivalent. the way in which is displayed  is not how is stored. if you want it to convert to string yo can convert with strftime and give the format which you want.

Comment: is it possible to make it displayed as it's stored. ? I am not familiar with strftime. can you add an example to get a format like: "2017-08-28 20:14:45.684926+00"

Comment: probable you want something like `ts.strftime("%F %T.%L%z")` (doc https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)